# Swift 2: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After I installed Xcode 7 beta and convert my swift code to Swift 2, I got some issue with the code that I can't figure out. I know Swift 2 is new so I search and figure out since there is nothing about it, I should write a question.

**Here is the error:**

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not
>   handled

**Code:**

```
func deleteAccountDetail(){
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AccountDetail", inManagedObjectContext: Context!)
        let request = NSFetchRequest()
        request.entity = entityDescription

        //The Line Below is where i expect the error
        let fetchedEntities = self.Context!.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [AccountDetail]

        for entity in fetchedEntities {
        self.Context!.deleteObject(entity)
        }

        do {
            try self.Context!.save()
        } catch _ {
        }

    }
```

**Snapshot:** 
[image]

Comment: Use this to resolve all. your code issues: https://chat.openai.com/g/g-3bzAm9iX3-telow

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You have to catch the error just as you're already doing for your `save()` call and since you're handling multiple errors here, you can `try` multiple calls sequentially in a single do-catch block, like so:

```
func deleteAccountDetail() {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AccountDetail", inManagedObjectContext: Context!)
    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    do {
        let fetchedEntities = try self.Context!.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [AccountDetail]

        for entity in fetchedEntities {
            self.Context!.deleteObject(entity)
        }

        try self.Context!.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Or as @bames53 pointed out in the comments below, it is often better practice not to catch the error where it was thrown. You can mark the method as `throws` then `try` to call the method. For example:

```
func deleteAccountDetail() throws {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AccountDetail", inManagedObjectContext: Context!)
    let request = NSFetchRequest()

    request.entity = entityDescription

    let fetchedEntities = try Context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [AccountDetail]

    for entity in fetchedEntities {
        self.Context!.deleteObject(entity)
    }

    try self.Context!.save()
}
```

Comment: Actually it's not required that the exception be caught here. It's possible to just add the `try` keyword to the function call, and to declare this function as `func deleteAccountDetail() throw`. Or if you've guaranteed that the function will not throw for the given input, you can use `try!`.

Comment: I bring this up not to nitpick, but because it's actually quite important to decent exception based error handling that most places where exceptions happen do not catch exceptions. There are three kinds of places where catching exceptions is appropriate. In all other places, code should not handle exceptions explicitly, and should rely on implicit `deinit()` calls to do clean up (i.e., RAII), or occasionally use `defer` to do some ad hoc cleanup. See exceptionsafecode.com for more (It talks about C++, but the basic principles apply to Swift exceptions as well.)

Comment: But how would you run the function? If I go with @bames53 way?

Comment: @bames53 Swift does not have en exception system. It has an *error* system. It's quite different to e.g. C++ exceptions. Your advice above does not really apply here. Swift errors are intended to be caught and handled locally.

Comment: @NickMoore What makes you say Swift's exceptions are different? They seem to be pretty much exactly the same as C++ exceptions except that the syntax is slightly different and Swift enforces an `ErrorType`.

Comment: @NickMoore What the Swift developers choose to call them does not make a difference in what they actually are. Swift's new error handling system is an implementation of exceptions as that term is commonly used throughout the rest of the industry.

Comment: Besides `try` or `try!`, `try?` can be used to wrap the result to an optional value.

Answer (score 48):

When calling a function that is declared with `throws` in Swift, you must annotate the function call site with `try` or `try!`. For example, given a throwing function:

```
func willOnlyThrowIfTrue(value: Bool) throws {
  if value { throw someError }
}
```

this function can be called like:

```
func foo(value: Bool) throws {
  try willOnlyThrowIfTrue(value)
}
```

Here we annotate the call with `try`, which calls out to the reader that this function may throw an exception, and any following lines of code might not be executed. We also have to annotate this function with `throws`, because this function could throw an exception (i.e., when `willOnlyThrowIfTrue()` throws, then `foo` will automatically rethrow the exception upwards.

If you want to call a function that is declared as possibly throwing, but which you know will not throw in your case because you're giving it correct input, you can use `try!`.

```
func bar() {
  try! willOnlyThrowIfTrue(false)
}
```

This way, when you guarantee that code won't throw, you don't have to put in extra boilerplate code to disable exception propagation.

`try!` is enforced at runtime: if you use `try!` and the function does end up throwing, then your program's execution will be terminated with a runtime error.

Most exception handling code should look like the above: either you simply propagate exceptions upward when they occur, or you set up conditions such that otherwise possible exceptions are ruled out. Any clean up of other resources in your code should occur via object destruction (i.e. `deinit()`), or sometimes via `defer`ed code.

```
func baz(value: Bool) throws {

  var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("theFile", ofType:"txt")
  var data = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath)

  try willOnlyThrowIfTrue(value)

  // data and filePath automatically cleaned up, even when an exception occurs.
}
```

If for whatever reason you have clean up code that needs to run but isn't in a `deinit()` function, you can use `defer`.

```
func qux(value: Bool) throws {
  defer {
    print("this code runs when the function exits, even when it exits by an exception")
  }

  try willOnlyThrowIfTrue(value)
}
```

---

Most code that deals with exceptions simply has them propagate upward to callers, doing cleanup on the way via `deinit()` or `defer`. This is because most code doesn't know what to do with errors; it knows what went wrong, but it doesn't have enough information about what some higher level code is trying to do in order to know what to do about the error. It doesn't know if presenting a dialog to the user is appropriate, or if it should retry, or if something else is appropriate.

Higher level code, however, should know exactly what to do in the event of any error. So exceptions allow specific errors to bubble up from where they initially occur to the where they can be handled.

Handling exceptions is done via `catch` statements.

```
func quux(value: Bool) {
  do {
    try willOnlyThrowIfTrue(value)
  } catch {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

You can have multiple catch statements, each catching a different kind of exception.

```
  do {
    try someFunctionThatThowsDifferentExceptions()
  } catch MyErrorType.errorA {
    // handle errorA
  } catch MyErrorType.errorB {
    // handle errorB
  } catch {
    // handle other errors
  }
```

---

For more details on best practices with exceptions, see http://exceptionsafecode.com/. It's specifically aimed at C++, but after examining the Swift exception model, I believe the basics apply to Swift as well.

For details on the Swift syntax and error handling model, see the book [*The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease)*](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id1002622538?mt=11).

Comment: Basically catch itself can handle the error? or input function

Comment: @BrianS I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, especially with regard to an 'input function', but 'catch' is essentially a synonym for 'handle' in the context of exceptions. That is to say, catching an exception and handling an exception are the same thing, as far as programming languages are concerned.

Comment: I have one error i quiet don't understand, Can you please help me? `Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> _' to non-throwing function type '(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void'`

Comment: @BrianS It sounds like you're using a function with an incorrect signature somewhere. Something expects to be given a function that takes `NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?` as arguments, but you're giving it a function that doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: Or something expects a function not declared to throw exceptions and you're giving it a function that does throw exceptions.

Comment: I have made separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738411/cannot-invoke-datataskwithrequest-with-an-argument-list-of-type-nsmutableurl/30740093#30740093

Comment: @LGL are you trying to put the problem code in `try{...}catch{...}` ?  if yes, then use `do{...}catch{...}` and add `try` or `try!` in front of the function call that is expected to generate exception.

Comment: @thesummersign I solve this long time ago. I approve correct answer.