# implementing swift's new try catch with older tutorial on connecting with my sql

Tags: swift, try-catch

Hi I'm struggling with implementing swifts new try catch with an older tutorial on connecting to a mysql database.

Here is the older tutorial's code:

```
func getPost(callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()){
    request("http://myurl.php", callback: callback)
}

func request(url:String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()){
    var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!){
        (data, response, error) in
        var error:NSError?
        var response = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as NSDictionary
        callback(response)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Here is my failing attempt to implement the try catch since it wants that instead of error in the response var

```
func getPost(callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()){
    request("http://url.php", callback: callback)
}

func request(url:String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()){
    var nsURL = NSURL(string: url)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!){
        (data, response, error) in

        do {
            var response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            callback(response)
        } catch error& {

        }



    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Id really appreciate someone helping with getting the syntax right, thanks!

**complete working code:**

```
func getFleet(){
    getPost{
        (response) in
        print(response)
    }
}

func getPost(callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()){
    request("http://url.com/SpaceAcademy/SaveFleet.php", callback: callback)
}

func request(url:String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()){
    let nsURL = NSURL(string: url)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!) { (data, nsURLResponse, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            //act on error from server
        } else {
            do {
                var response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                callback(response)
            } catch {
                // act on thrown error
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30737262/2556515

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catch doesn't catch the error from the server only the error that can be thrown when parsing the json data. You need to handle them both.

```
func request(url:String, callback:(NSDictionary) -> ()){
    let nsURL = NSURL(string: url)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!) { (data, nsURLResponse, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            //act on error from server
        } else {
            do {
                var response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                callback(response)
            } catch {
                // act on thrown error
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```