# Handling a conversion error in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, textfield

I have a text field. In my code I convert `myTextField.text` into an integer.  If I wanted to handle an error in the event in which someone types in an input other than an `Int`, how would I handle this in Swift 2.0?

Comment: `Try, do, catch` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737262/swift-2-call-can-throw-but-it-is-not-marked-with-try-and-the-error-is-not-ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `init?(_ text: String, radix: Int = default)` constructor for `Int` which returns an `Int?` (optional `Int`) which will be `nil` if the value isn't an `Int`.  Use *optional binding* `if let` to handle the two cases:

```
if let value = Int(myTextField.text ?? "") {
    // use value which is an Int
} else {
    print("value was not an Int")
}
```

Note:  Since `myTextField.text` is a `String?` it might be `nil`, so use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to use empty string `""` when it is `nil`.  This safely unwraps `myTextField.text` or uses `""`.

---

If you have a *default value* in mind for the case in which a valid `Int` has not been entered, then you could use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to assign that value:

```
// Use 0 if the value is not an Int
let value = Int(myTextField.text ?? "") ?? 0
```