# Swift 2 : Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: json, swift, swift2, itunes

i'm beginning with Swift 2,  and i have this error while trying to finalize a function that tries to use iTunes API.

```
    func searchItunesFor(searchTerm: String) {
    let itunesSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

    if let escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let urlPath = "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(escapedSearchTerm)&media=software"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Task completed")
            if(error != nil) {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            var err: NSError?
            if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                if(err != nil) {
                    print("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                if let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.tableData = results
                        self.appsTableView!.reloadData()
                    })
                }
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

i get the error : "" Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled "" on this line

```
if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
            if(err != nil) {
```

What's the solution to this problem ?
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737262/swift-2-call-can-throw-but-it-is-not-marked-with-try-and-the-error-is-not-ha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because not all `NSData` can be converted to JSON objects. Replace that JSON parsing part with this:

```
do {
    if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableData = results
            self.appsTableView!.reloadData()
        })
    }
} catch let jsonError as NSError {
    print(jsonError.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**You can also use somehting like this..**
using, ObjectMapper, SwiftyJSON, Alafir

```
        guard let jsonResponce = try? JSON(data: data) else {
            print("\n\n\n\n error :\(AppAlertMsg.kErrorMsg) \n\n URL:\(urlString) \n\n paramaters:\(JSON(paramaters as Any))\n\n\n\n")
            failure("error")
            return
        }
```