# Swift 4.0.3 , Alamofire , Swiftyjson JSON 'try' and the error is not handled error

Tags: json, alamofire, swift4, swifty-json

I have working project on `swift4` with `xcode9` but when I download and use my project with `Xcode9.2` and `Swift4.0.3` gives me my working code;

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled Error

**Im using , `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON`**

My codes under below

```
 Alamofire.request(PostUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
                        .responseData{ response in
                            if response.result.value != nil {
                              let json =  JSON(data:response.result.value!)
                                let success = json["Result"]

                                if success == true {

                                print("ok")

                                }else{

}

}
}
```

error line

> let json =  JSON(data:response.result.value!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737262/swift-2-call-can-throw-but-it-is-not-marked-with-try-and-the-error-is-not-ha)

Comment: @vadian no this is using swifty json and alamofire don't  coredata try catch

Comment: The API is irrelevant. Every API which *can throw* behaves exactly the same and has to be handled exactly the same. The error message *... is not marked with 'try'...* is pretty clear.

Comment: @how can I fix this error ?

Comment: Please read [The Swift Programming Language: Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508). It's a very common pattern. As a *SwiftDeveloper* you are supposed to know that. 